# Required code cannot access main code

Tags: javascript

so I was trying to bring my code to readable form but stumbled upon a kinda annoying problem.

So I wanted to outsource a class into an file, "require" it and than write the callback function in the main file for the readability. But the function in the outsourced file is not able to access the callback function. Here is the simplified problem:

file_a.js

```
function test_a(){
    return "this is A"
}

var test_b = require('./lib/file_b.js').test_b
console.log(test_b())
```

file_b.js

```
function test_b(){
    return test_a()
}
exports.test_b = test_b
```

I hope someone could tell me how to manage this problem :)
EDIT: This code is for a firefox addon !

Comment: pass `test_a` to `test_b`?

Comment: What is the issue you are  having? Your test_b function doesn't return anything, it just runs another method, so I would expect to see undefined in the console from what is there....

Comment: This is one of of the benefits of using module loaders - each module is isolated to it's own scope, so you avoid something called "scope pollution". What it boils down to is that you have precise control over what tokens (variables, functions, etc) are available in what scope, but you must explicitly define what is in each scope, it's no longer "automatic" (global). In this case, it's probably best to pass `test_a` into `test_b` as @PatrickEvans suggested.

Comment: PatrickEvans well the real problem is not that simple and I am not able to just pass it through sadly. Toby it just says that test_a is not defined as the scope seems not be wide enough, btw. this is within a firefox addon.

Comment: Just to add it up, there is no way to display function test_a to test_b other than passing it as an argument ?

Comment: If not then demonstrate why you cannot. We cannot help you if we dont know all the details

Comment: Ok well the code is kinda big, it should be transferred to a listener. Give me a second I might have a idea how to solve this.

Comment: Ok I found a really sloppy solution which is just a function which takes the reference for the function and puts it into a variable which gets used in the actual context.

Comment: Why not require `test_a` in `test_b` instead of the other way around?

Comment: @MichaelL. that might be a idea but this would not increase the readability :/

Comment: You could also try dependency injection. See this page on [best practices in nodejs](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-best-practices-part-2/) and scroll down to the bits on dependency injection. Yes, I know you're not using node, but whatever you are using appears to be using the same CommonJS model.

Answer (score 0):

`test_a` function has to be globally defined:

```
test_a = function(){
    return "this is A"
}

var test_b = require('./lib/file_b.js').test_b
console.log(test_b())
```

Also, you have to return something in your `test_b` function:

```
function test_b(){
    return test_a()
}
exports.test_b = test_b
```

Then you will have such output:

> this is A

Comment: This did not help the function is still not defined in the scope of the second function.

Comment: Btw. this is for a firefox addon :/

Comment: @Feirell You should have mentioned that in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can load both js files independently in the same HTML file.

Then, whichever code that you have that is referencing other files loaded on the page should be in a window.onload call (or using jQuery $(document).ready), so that it only runs when the two files are available on the page.

Comment: It's a Node.js question I believe.

Comment: Sorry I did not specified this but this code is within a firefox addon so this would help :(